# Splitting a string

Tags: php, algorithm, encryption

I have created an encryption algorithm in which I need to reverse, I need to separate a string into pairs of 3 into an array, I have looked all over and have found no help, how would I do this?

Edit:
I have tried:

```
<?php
$todecode="#number too big to post#";
$len=strlen($todecode);
$a=0;
$b=array();
While($len!=$a){
//$decoded=chunk_split($todecode);
$add1=$todecode[$a];
$a=$a+1;
$add2=$todecode[$a];
$a=$a+1;
$add3=$todecode[$a];
$a=$a+1;
$adder=$add1,$add2,$add3;
array_push($b,$adder);
}
```

But nothing else yet.

Comment: What's your question? What have you tried?

Comment: I need to split a string like 928473838485948484838485 into groups of 3. What code can do this?

Comment: @ToQwertyForYou Show us what you've tried.

Comment: Can you please post what have you tried? Describing the problem and the desired solution is not enough. Check this article: http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: Try to use explode or str_split functions.

Comment: Look on php.net and browse through string functions. Also it is really safest to only use published methods for encryption

Comment: do you need it to be 3 same sized strings or does it need to be split up into different sized strings?

Comment: "I have created an encryption algorithm" and none of the existing ones where of any use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $num_str = "12312312315234535";
    print_r(str_split($num_str,3));
```

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/gHH4Yp

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, short and precise. Thank you.

Comment: I misread the question; my bad.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know PHP, but I can provide a suggestion on what you must do.

First, you need to count the characters of your string, and create the 3 cell arrays you need:

- If you string has 19 chars, then you will need `ceil(19 / 3) = 7` arrays, or (better) a 7-by-3 array

Then you'll need to store the chars on every row of the array:

```
i = -1; j=0;
for(j=0; j<length_of_your_string; j++) {
    if (j % 3 == 0)
        i++;
    result_array[i][j % 3] = your_string.charAt(j);
}
```

I leave to you the translation to something you can use.